# How do I remove all duplicate entries from one nested dictionary that appear in another?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

Assuming my dictionaries are set up like this:

```
dict_a = {"first_key": {"second_key": "value1", "third_key": "value2"}}
dict_b = {"first_key": {"third_key": "value2"}}
```

I want to be left with this:

```
dict_a = {first_key: {second_key: value1}}
```

I've tried a few different ways of getting there like this:

```
dict(dica_a.items() - dict_b.items())
```

But that tells me dicts are unhashable. Trying this method:

```
dict_c = {k:dict_a[k] for k in dict_a if k not in dict_b}
```

Leaves me with an empty dictionary. I also tried this:

```
for k, v in dict_b.items():
    if (k, v) in dict_a.itemS():
        dict_a.pop(k, v)
```

But again, no luck there. It ended up not modifying dict_a at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
additional_key_to_remove = []

for key, value in dict_b.items():
    if isinstance(dict_a[key], dict) and isinstance(
        value, dict
    ):  # to makes sure that operation are happening on dictionary and not on any other datastructures
        sub_dict = dict_a[key]
        for k in value:
            sub_dict.pop(k, None)
    elif isinstance(dict_a[key], str) and isinstance(
        value, str
    ):  # collect the non nested keys for later removal
        additional_key_to_remove.append(key)

for key in additional_key_to_remove:
    del dict_a[key]

print(dict_a)
```

**Output:**

```
{'first_key': {'second_key': 'value1'}}
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution. Would you be able to expound on what it's doing and why? Additionally, how would I go about making it work for additional top level keys? Example:

    dict_a = {"first_key": {"second_key": "value1", "third_key": "value2"}, "sixth_key": "test"}
    dict_b = {"first_key": {"third_key": "value2"}, "sixth_key": "test"}

Will leave us with 

    {'first_key': {'second_key': 'value1'}, 'sixth_key': 'test'}

Instead of 

    {'first_key': {'second_key': 'value1'}}

Comment: @AlecRitter Its hard to explain the whole code in plain English but I've added comments.

Comment: @AlecRitter I've updated the answer to include the additional functionality.